# Unable to remove escape character from my XML string

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I am building an XML string from 3 parts:

1. the before bit which is hard-coded
2. the middle bit which is created from object serialization
3. the after bit which is also hardcoded.

No matter what I do, I cannot remove the escape characters from it though, and this is causing failed requests when I use that XML string in the request object that it is intended for.

Code (and my attempts at this) below:

```
string preceedingXml = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:enl=\"http://company.com\"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><enl:Combine>";
            string afterXml = "</enl:Combine></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>";
try
            {
                using (var stringwriter = new System.IO.StringWriter())
                {
                    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(this.GetType());
                    serializer.Serialize(stringwriter, this);

                    var requestXML = XDocument.Parse(stringwriter.ToString())
                       .Descendants("in")
                       .First();

                    string unescaped = Regex.Unescape(requestXML.ToString().Replace("\r\n", ""));
                    string returnValue = preceedingXml +unescaped + afterXml;
                    string rd = returnValue.Replace("\\'", "'");
                    string rd3 = returnValue.Replace(@"\", string.Empty);
                    string rd4 = RemoveSpecialChars(returnValue);
                    string rd5 = returnValue.Trim('"');

                    return returnValue; 
            
                }
                
            }
```

The result is always the same no matter what:

```
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"
    xmlns:enl=\"http://company.com/product\">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <enl:Combine>
            <in
                xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"
                xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">
                <returnAllRecords>0</returnAllRecords>
                <projectName>Project</projectName>
                <lhs>
                    <recordType>ParsedData</recordType>
                    <recordId>1000000</recordId>
                    <data>
                        <fields name=\"Full-Name\">
                            <values>John Smith</values>
etc.
```

Comment: Chances are those `"\"` characters aren't actually part of the string; it's just how the Visual Studio debugger displays them. What is the *actual* problem with the request?

Comment: In the VS debugger you can use text or XML visualization of a string to avoid having it show escape characters, is that what you've done?